# How to choose a specific bean implementation without using qualifier?

Tags: cdi

I am providing implementation of an injected service interface at runtime , through a `producer` in my app.

Recently, another implementation of the same service interface has been created by someone in a collaborating team and that class has been added in a jar I can not avoid in my application. This is therefore throwing `ambiguous dependency exception` which I can obviously solve through a CDI qualifier on my producer method and at injection point. I wanted to ask if there is any other way to avoid this overhead. Can I use my `@Produces` method as the default implementation to make container ignore the second implementation? I added `@Default` annotation along with `@Produces` annotation on the producer method to check if this solves the problem since every injection by default is annotated with `@Default`. But that didn't work.

Comment: Maybe by using @Any qualifier? This is occasionally also a qualifier, but embedded. 
We often use it if we need to select an implementation on run time. Some kind of plugins. But you will need of course some other way to find your implementation in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the following options to avoid the overhead to create a new qualifier for a new implementation.

1. Use the built-in qualifier `@Named` which allows you specify an implementation by String. (But it does not use CDI type safe injection feature)
2. Create one qualifier that has the enum attribute. Each enum value represents an implementation . Which implementation to be injected is specified by this enum attribute. (Injection is type safe. See [this](http://buraktas.com/create-qualifiers-cdi-beans/) for an example)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't annotate the second implementation using `@Vetoed`, I would write a CDI extension that vetoes the class via `ProcessAnnotatedType`

```
private void vetoSecondImpl(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<YourSecondImpl> pat) {
    pat.veto();
}
```

Here's a reference from the spec: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#init_events